# How remove iFrame from wordpress admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I've some problem with iframe at the WordPress admin panel. Can you tell how to remove it? and how to secure WordPress with similar problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation.](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) If you use NetSol for hosting, see [WordPress › Support » attack on wpress 2.9.2](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/385477?replies=135)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/261886) is a discussion of how many others have fixed this.